Acer Wifi and Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I installed ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my new acer aspire Lite AL 15-41, but unfortunately neither bluetooth nor wifi works on the system. I am new to Linux and just tried some command I figured out from different blogs. Here are the output of those:
~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1558:a600]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5521]
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5019-E19 PCIe4 NVMe Controller (DRAM-less) [1987:5019] (rev 01)

~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:3580 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 

~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for sudeepsudha: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: d4:93:90:3a:67:75
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:52 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0704000-d0704fff memory:d0700000-d0703fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fcf0200000-fcf02fffff memory:d0600000-d0607fff

Could someone help me resolve the issue?

A search for 14c3:7902 brings up MT7902, and reports of unsupported hardware. Not sure if there is a solution yet.

How about Bluetooth? Does that also have same problem? I face the same issue with Bluetooth as well

Don't know if this helps? https://www.linux.org/threads/ubuntu-22-04-wifi-driver-not-found-mediatek-mt7921e.45953/
